# Authenticating Rails Application With Omniauth Github in Local

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, github, omniauth

I am working on authenticating users using GitHub in local development mode.

I am using using [omniauth-github](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth-github) Rubygem.

I have bellow code in **config/initializers/omniauth.rb**

```
OmniAuth.config.logger = Rails.logger

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
 provider :github, ENV['GITHUB_KEY'], ENV['GITHUB_SECRET'],
    {
      :client_options => {
        :site => 'https://github.com/api/v3',
        :authorize_url => 'https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize',
        :token_url => 'https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token',
      }
    }
end
```

In view layout I have

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Github", "/auth/github" %>
```

In **routes.rb** I have

```
  match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'session#create', :via => [:get, :post]
  match 'signout' => 'session#destroy', :via => [:delete], :as => 'signout'
```

I have registered new application in github with 
**Homepage URL** : http://localhost:3000
, **Authorization callback URL** : http://localhost:3000/callback

After clicking on **Sign in with Github**, I am getting following error.

```
http://localhost:3000/callback?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The redirect_uri MUST match the registered callback URL for this application.&error_uri=https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#redirect-uri-mismatch&state=14216a2416431297d9690e68efe0723a03aa7a1eaee51db3
```

Kindly help me to set proper values for site ,authorize_url , token_url to work in local system.

Comment: output of `rake routes | grep callback` please?

Comment: From the description so far, i think you need to change your registered callback url from `http://localhost:3000/callback` to `http://localhost:3000/auth/github/callback`. See if it works.

Comment: Thank you for quit solution, Yes you are right it did worked. But I am getting again new error. Please find the logs

Started GET "/auth/github/callback?code=9b83c44089bfffa0296c&state=648895e88fd34b8c9c43c3de95c8033da49f99d8dbe17182" for ::1 at 2017-01-03 13:54:58 +0530
(github) Callback phase initiated.
(github) Authentication failure! invalid_credentials: OAuth2::Error, Not Found: 
{"error":"Not Found"}

OAuth2::Error (Not Found: 
{"error":"Not Found"}):
  oauth2 (1.3.0) lib/oauth2/client.rb:119:in `request'